# How to interact with a BSC contract using Python

Tags: web3.py, python

Binance Smart Chain. I've first tried sending a transaction with python:

```
from web3 import Web3

transaction = {
        'chainId': 97,  # 97: Testnet. 56: main.
        'to': '0xmyaddress',
        'value': 1,
        'gas': 2000000,
        'gasPrice': 13,
        'nonce': 0,
    }

infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/my-api-key"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

key = '0xmykey'
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, key)

w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Giving me the following error: ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid sender'}

---

Now, I am trying to interact with a contract - calling methods and giving inputs, but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Infura does not support 56 nor 97 chain ids.
These are for BSC, infura only supports Ethereum
I suggest using Binance official node url for BSC Mainnet (56): https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/
Or chainId 97 BSC Testnet: https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/

Comment: You have working python code with Binance Node?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I'm not a programmer and don't really know what im talking about but I don't think you can use infura to call the BSC net.  I think infura is for use with etherium.   Check this link for the mainnet url for BSC.

https://docs.fortmatic.com/web3-integration/binance-smart-chain

Comment: Hi and welcome, indeed currently Infura doesn't support Eth, one can use binance chain api: https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/ , but the current support for Python is in the air.